# Multiple GemInABox hosts

Tags: geminabox

I know I can configure which host to upload gems to with:

```
gem inabox -c
```

**How can I tell `geminabox` to upload to multiple hosts at the same time?** We have two gem servers, and when I run:

```
gem inabox my_custom_gem.gem
```

I'd like for it to upload to both of our private gem servers.